# What is a good tool or software for generating curved lines for Latex graphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, draw, technical-drawing

For example, I want to generate the following images,
[image]

or

[image]

I am using LaTexdraw at the moment but it seems to be very bad at generating curves. What would be a good choice for generating these curves for Latex graphics?

Comment: This is opinion based question. The best for you is one by which you are the most familiar :-). For diagrams I use `pgfplots`, for other (nontechnical) drawings I use `tikz`. Many people use `psdraw` and `metapost`.

Comment: Hi! I literally only know tikz out of those you mentioned. So I've already learned crazy amount from a short comment.

Comment: `pgfplots` is based on `tikz`. For both exist very good (and huge) documentation and collections of examples: http://pgfplots.net/ and https://texample.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) is a great program for vector graphics.

It allows to embed latex equations (Extensions > Render > Mathematics > Pdflatex).

[image]

The images are `.svg` so you need to use `\includesvg` to embed them in your tex document. Rendering quality is optimal, much better than in the above `.png` export.

The only drawback is that generated elements are not linked to the source latex code. You can install the [textext](https://textext.github.io/textext/) extension if working with long or complicated equations.

Comment: In addition, you can also save your inkscape graphic as .eps and import it with \includegraphics

Answer (score 3):

This is a starting for you. IMHO, Asymptote's `path`s can be managed in clearer
and easier way (try TikZ to compare!)

[image]

```
//http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
pair A=(0,0), B=(3,0);
real h=4;
path p= A .. controls A+dir(55) and B+1.5*dir(-120) .. B;
path q=shift(0,h)*reverse(p);
filldraw(p--relpoint(q,0)--q--cycle,pink,blue);
shipout(bbox(5mm));
```